# Checking proof of fact about local path-connectedness

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove that if $X$ is locally path-connected, then the path-connected and connected components are equal. I take as a lemma that local path-connectedness implies the path-connected components are open.

First, fix $x \in X$, and let $C$ denote the connected component containing $x$ (i.e. the largest connected set containing $x$) and $P$ the path-connected component containing $x$ (i.e. the equivalence class $[x]$ corresponding to the equivalence relation $x \sim y$ iff there exists a continuous map $\gamma : [0, 1] \to X$ such that $\gamma(0) = x, \gamma(1) = y$). That $P \subseteq C$ follows from the fact that path-connectedness implies connectedness. Now assume for contradiction $C \setminus P \neq \emptyset$.

We claim that $C \setminus P$ is open. Let $c \in C \setminus P$ be arbitrary. Then since $X$ is locally path-connected, there exists a path-connected neighborhood $N \ni c$, which we claim is contained in $C \setminus P$. Firstly, note that if $\exists p \in N \cap P$, then $x \sim p \sim c \Rightarrow x \sim c \Rightarrow c \in P$. Thus $N \cap P = \emptyset$. Moreover, since $N$ is path-connected, it is *a fortiori* connected, so $N \subseteq C$. Thus $N$ is a neighborhood about $c$ contained in $C \setminus P$. Therefore $C \setminus P$ is open.

But we also note that $P$ is path-connected, and therefore open. Moreover, $x \in P \Rightarrow P \neq \emptyset$. Thus if $C \setminus P \neq \emptyset$, then $\{ P , C \setminus P \}$ separates $C$. But $C$ is connected, so we have a contradiction. Therefore $C \setminus P = \emptyset$, so $C \subseteq P$, establishing equality.

Does this proof work?

Comment: First paragraph makes sense to me.